# Show that $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\Psi} \left(\frac{d\Psi}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{d^2\Psi}{dx^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I think I have the proof, but I'm not completely sure.

I'm sorry for not giving my solution now, I'm on my phone.

Edit:

$1/2 d/dy(dy/dx)^2 = 1/2 (d^2y/(dx^2dy)+d^2y/(dx^2dy) = d^2y/dx^2$

Really not sure at all...

Comment: Why don't you add your solution to your question so that we can judge it?

Comment: Just use chain rule

Comment: Did you mean for the outer derivative to be $d/dx$?

Comment: In your second fraction should it be $\;dx\;$ instead of $\;d\Psi\;$ in the denominator?

Comment: Even with the probable change above, I don't get that equality...

Comment: @Timbuc, it's written correctly. I'm not writing my solution because I'm in a restaurant, writing with a phone. Completely impractical. Sorry

Comment: @davcha, then it should **also** be impractical (and even impolitically correct, but that's not my business) to ask a question without showing some self work. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Timbuc,  just because you don't get the equality, i don't see a reason why it should be closed.

Comment: @abel That's not the reason at all, but because the OP showed no self work towards solving his question. Saying he's in a restaurant with his phone writing is a rather weak pretext for me. BTW, as the answers show, that I didn't get equality was due to my lack of ability to solve the problem, as it seems to be it was correctly posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i will use $y$ instead of $\Psi.$
$$\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \dfrac{dx}{dy} =\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{dy}{dx} \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Comment: Yes, although these formulas (and the OP) are in desperate need of clarification of what is a function of what, and what is being differentiated with respect to what.

Comment: No need for me, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

$${1 \over 2}{d \over d\Psi}\left( {d\Psi \over dx}\right)^2$$
$$={1 \over 2}\cdot{2}\cdot\left( {d\Psi \over dx}\right)\left[{d \over d\Psi}\left( {d\Psi \over dx}\right)\right]$$
$$=\left( {d\Psi \over dx}\right)\left[{d \over dx}\left( {d\Psi \over dx}\right)\right]\left( {dx \over d\Psi}\right)$$
$$={d^2\Psi \over d^2x}$$